# direct message sync issue with twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I am using the twitter api to get all direct messages

while testing I tried to delete a message from the twitter website and then tried to reload my app's direct message page (get via api) - the dm I deleted was still showing in my app but it wasn't on the account I was using on the website.

I'm not sure whats going on here, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You usually should give a second after an update/delete operation on Twitter. If you do, I would say that something is going wrong with your code.